# Most Efficient Way to get list of values from Django Queryset

Tags: python, django, list, filter, django-queryset

I can see quite a few different options for doing this and would like some feedback on the most efficient or 'best practice' method.

I get a Django Queryset with filter()

```
c_layer_points = models.layer_points.objects.filter(location_id=c_location.pk,season_id=c_season.pk,line_path_id=c_line_path.pk,radar_id=c_radar.pk,layer_id__in=c_layer_pks,gps_time__gte=start_gps,gps_time__lte=stop_gps)
```

This queryset could be very large (hundreds of thousands of rows).

Now what needs to happen is a conversion to lists and encoding to JSON.

Options (that i've seen in my searches):

1. Loop over the queryset

Example:

```
gps_time = [lp.gps_time for lp in c_layer_points];
twtt = [lp.twtt for lp in c_layer_points];
```

1. Use values() or values_list()
2. Use iterator()

In the end I would like to encode as json something like this format:

```
{'gps_time':[list of all gps times],'twtt',[list of all twtt]}
```

Any hints on the best way to do this would be great, Thanks!

Comment: Why wouldn't you just do the measurements yourself? `import datetime; start = datetime.time(); <do your stuff> end = datetime.time(); print(end-start)`

Comment: I have and will continue to do this. However I wanted to get a feel from others on what "best practice" would be here. Especially since a few of the options are nearly the same from an efficiency standpoint.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might not be able to get the required format from the ORM. However, you can efficiently do something like this:

```
c_layer_points = models.layer_points.objects.filter(
    location_id=c_location.pk,
    season_id=c_season.pk, 
    line_path_id=c_line_path.pk,
    radar_id=c_radar.pk,
    layer_id__in=c_layer_pks,
    gps_time__gte=start_gps, 
    gps_time__lte=stop_gps
).values_list('gps_time', 'twtt')
```

and now split the tuples into two lists: (Tuple unpacking)

```
split_lst = zip(*c_layer_points)    
dict(gps_time=list(split_lst[0]), twtt=list(split_lst[1]))
```

Comment: Note that even with `.values_list()` (or `.iterator()` or anything else as best I can tell), django will read all the records into memory. Great for SQL performance, not so great for memory if we're talking about large rows. My python process used > 300 mb of RAM. I ended up using `Paginator` to loop through chunks of records. Memory vs speed is a tradeoff, and I settled on 10,000 records at a time.

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest you use the iterate through the query set and conform the json dictionary element by element from the queryset.

Normally, Django's QuerySets are lazy, this means they get load into memory whenever they get accessed. If you load the entire list: `gps_time = [lp.gps_time for lp in c_layer_points]` you will have all those objects in memory (thousands). You'll be good by doing a simple iteration:

```
for item in c_layer_points:
    #convert item to json and add it to the
    #json dict.
```

As an aside note, you don't need the `;` character at the end of lines in python :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great i'll take a look at this. Also I know on the ";" MATLAB is my primary language (this is changing!) so it's just a dirty habit!

Comment: Hehehe been there, I programmed in C++, C# before ;)

Comment: I'm not sure this will work for me. I actually need to do some operations on the data (meaning I really have to load it into memory as lists). For example I have to do some interpolation based on the items in c_layer_points.